# How can I read and parse chunks of data into a Perl hash of arrays?

Tags: perl, data-structures

I have data that looks like this:

```
#info
#info2

1:SRX004541
Submitter: UT-MGS, UT-MGS
Study: Glossina morsitans transcript sequencing project(SRP000741)
Sample: Glossina morsitans(SRS002835)
Instrument: Illumina Genome Analyzer
Total: 1 run, 8.3M spots, 299.9M bases
Run #1: SRR016086, 8330172 spots, 299886192 bases

2:SRX004540
Submitter: UT-MGS
Study: Anopheles stephensi transcript sequencing project(SRP000747)
Sample: Anopheles stephensi(SRS002864)
Instrument: Solexa 1G Genome Analyzer
Total: 1 run, 8.4M spots, 401M bases
Run #1: SRR017875, 8354743 spots, 401027664 bases

3:SRX002521
Submitter: UT-MGS
Study: Massive transcriptional start site mapping of human cells under hypoxic conditions.(SRP000403)
Sample: Human DLD-1  tissue culture cell line(SRS001843)
Instrument: Solexa 1G Genome Analyzer
Total: 6 runs, 27.1M spots, 977M bases
Run #1: SRR013356, 4801519 spots, 172854684 bases
Run #2: SRR013357, 3603355 spots, 129720780 bases
Run #3: SRR013358, 3459692 spots, 124548912 bases
Run #4: SRR013360, 5219342 spots, 187896312 bases
Run #5: SRR013361, 5140152 spots, 185045472 bases
Run #6: SRR013370, 4916054 spots, 176977944 bases
```

What I want to do is to create a hash of array with first line of each chunk as keys
and SR## part of lines with "^Run" as its array member:

```
$VAR = {
     'SRX004541' => ['SRR016086'], 
     # etc
}
```

But why my construct doesn't work. And it must be a better way to do it.

```
use Data::Dumper;
my %bighash;
my $head = "";
my @temp = ();

while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    next if (/^\#/);


    if ( /^\d{1,2}:(\w+)/ ) { 
print "$1\n";
      $head = $1;


    }
    elsif (/^Run \#\d+: (\w+),.*/){ 
print "\t$1\n";
      push @temp, $1;
    }
    elsif (/^$/) {
         push @{$bighash{$head}}, [@temp];
         @temp =();
    }

}               


print Dumper \%bighash ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative way to do parsing like this is to read entire paragraphs. For more information on the input record separator (`$/`), see [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
my %bighash;

{
    local $/ = "\n\n"; # Read entire paragraphs.
    while (my $paragraph = <>){
        # Filter out comments and handle extra blank lines between sections.
        my @lines = grep {/\S/ and not /^\#/} split /\n/, $paragraph;
        next unless @lines;

        # Extract the key and the SRR* items.
        my $key = $lines[0];
        $key =~ s/^\d+://;
        $bighash{$key} = [map { /^Run \#\d+: +(SRR\d+)/ ? $1 : () } @lines];
    }
}

print Dumper(\%bighash);
```

Comment: Absolutely. There is really no need to mess with anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
push @{$bighash{$head}}, [@temp];
```

with

```
push @{$bighash{$head}}, @temp;
```

You only have one array per `$head` value, right? The second statement adds all the values in `@temp` to the arrayref in `$bighash{$head}`. The *first* form, on the other hand, constructs an array reference out of the items in `@temp` and pushes *that* to `$bighash{$head}`, giving you an arrayref of arrayrefs.

Alternately you might want

```
$bighash{$head} = [@temp];
```

If you only expect to encounter each `$head` value once.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, here is one way to do it

```
my $head;
my %result;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    next if (/^\#/);

    if ( /^\d{1,2}:(\w+)/ ) {
        $result{$1} = []; 
        $head = $1; # $head will be used to know which key the following values
                    # will be assigned to
    }
    elsif (/^Run \#\d+: (\w+),.*/) {
        push(@{$result{$head}},$1); #Add the number found to the array that is assigned to the                        
                                    #last key found
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your state machine, I think you may use this logic:

```
if(!$head)
{
  # seek and get head
} 
else
{
  if (!$total) 
  {
    # seek and get total
  }
  else
  {
    # seek run
    # if found :
      # push run to temp and decrease total
      # if total eq 0 :
        # push temp to bighash
        # reset head, total and temp
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct but I'll strongly recommend adding:

```
use warnings
use strict
```

in everything but the most trivial one liners, also add

```
 elsif ($head && /^$/) {
```

to your last condition, to catch problems.

Comment: @piotr: it still doesn't work. There is duplicate of arrays inside each hash.

Comment: can you paste your Dumper output?